Issue with Executing Head_link Commands on MoveIt and Anomaly in Gazebo
I am experiencing an issue with controlling the head of the R1 robot via MoveIt, and I hope someone can help me resolve it. This is for a university project.
Current Situation
I successfully resolved an initial problem regarding the head joints package, and currently, the "plan and execute" command on MoveIt works as expected. However, there is an anomaly when executing commands in Gazebo: the robot's head does not move in the correct direction and always tends to move downward.
Debugging Steps Taken
To understand the cause of this problem, I ran MoveIt in pipe with grep ERROR, but no errors were detected. Therefore, I have no clues on how to resolve the issue.
Topic Analysis
I analyzed the ros2_cb_msgs/position topic, comparing its publications with the positions indicated in both MoveIt and yarpmotorgui. Here is what I observed:

Second-to-Last Publication:

Joint 1: 0.4122986837000703 rad -> 23.62247 degrees
Joint 2: 0.34879898507468576 rad -> 19.98419 degrees (corresponding to MoveIt)


Last Publication:

Joint 1: 0.4466447987119153 rad -> 25.59058 degrees
Joint 2: -0.01792537135895156 rad -> -1.02674 degrees (corresponding to yarpmotorgui)



The last publication of the topic seems to be consistent with the yarpmotorgui parameters, while the second-to-last publication is closer to the MoveIt parameters. However, it remains unclear why there are differences between the positions indicated by MoveIt and yarpmotorgui and their respective publications.
Command Input
The command given in input was intended to move the head to the following position:

neck_pitch_joint = 24°
neck_yaw_joint = 20°

Attached Materials
For further clarity, I have attached the following materials:

A screenshot of the ros2_cb_msgs/position topic showing the last and second-to-last publications.
An image from MoveIt representing the joint positions that I input.
A screenshot of yarpmotorgui showing the joint positions on Gazebo.

If necessary, I can also provide the code.
Question:
Does anyone have any ideas on what might be causing this discrepancy in the head movement on Gazebo? Do you have suggestions for further debugging steps or configurations to check?
Thank you in advance for any help you can provide!



